# Change ListView item visibilty when another item in same row is clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with one `CheckBox` and one `EditText`. I want to make the `EditText` visible when the `CheckBox` is checked in each row. Currently I've set the visibility of `EditText` to `GONE`

This is my Adapter class:

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cheese> {

        private ArrayList<Cheese> cheeseList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Cheese> cheeseList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, cheeseList);
            this.cheeseList = new ArrayList<Cheese>();
            this.cheeseList.addAll(cheeseList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            EditText code;
            CheckBox name;
        }

  @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder = null;
                Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cheese_info, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.code = (EditText) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);

                    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                            Cheese country = (Cheese) cb.getTag();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                            + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                            ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                            holder1.code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                Cheese country = cheeseList.get(position);
                holder.name.setText(country.getName());
                holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
                holder.name.setTag(country);

                return convertView;

            }

        }
```

I tried adding

```
ViewHolder holder1 = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
holder1.code.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

inside `CheckBox` click. But application is getting crashed giving error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.viewpagersample.Cheese
>   cannot be cast to
>   com.example.viewpagersample.MainActivity$MyCustomAdapter$ViewHolder

Comment: Try to manipulate the visibility via your Cheese object and use setOnItemClickListener outside your adapter!

Comment: i thought the problem is with this line  holder.name.setTag(country);

Comment: you are trying assign set Cheese object in tag instead of viewholder

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. I have to get the parent ViewGroup and find the 
EditText and change visibility like below:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup=(ViewGroup)v.getParent();
EditText quantity=(EditText)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cheese> {

        private ArrayList<Cheese> cheeseList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Cheese> cheeseList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, cheeseList);
            this.cheeseList = new ArrayList<Cheese>();
            this.cheeseList.addAll(cheeseList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            EditText code;
            CheckBox name;
        }

  @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder = null;
                Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cheese_info, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.code = (EditText) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);


                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                Cheese country = cheeseList.get(position);
                holder.name.setText(country.getName());
                holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
                holder.name.setTag(country);
holder.name.setOnClickListener(new Listener(country,holder.name,holder.code));
                return convertView;

            }
class Listener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    Cheese country;
     CheckBox cb;
     EditText view;
    Listener(Cheese country, CheckBox cb,EditText view)
    {
    this.country = country;
    this.cb = cb;
    this.view = view;
    }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                            + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

        }
    }

        }
```